# Can a child object refer to its parent during deinit of the parent?

Tags: swift, deinit

I have a parent class and a child class. The parent has a strong reference to the child, and the child has an unowned reference to the parent. During deinit of the parent, I want the child to do some cleaning up, and that involves calling the parent:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController
{
    override func viewDidLoad()
    {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let parent = Parent()
    }
}

class Parent : NSObject
{
    override init()
    {
        super.init()

        child.doStuff()
    }

    deinit
    {
        child.doStuff()
    }

    lazy private var child : Child = Child(parent : self)
}

class Child : NSObject
{
    init(parent : NSObject)
    {
        self.parent = parent
    }

    func doStuff()
    {
        println(self.parent)
    }

    deinit
    {

    }

    private unowned var parent : NSObject
}
```

Unfortunately, calling `doStuff()` during deinit of the parent causes a crash, as it uses `self.parent`:

```
libswiftCore.dylib`_swift_abortRetainUnowned:
    0x111e91740 <+0>:  leaq   0x1e6cd(%rip), %rax       ; "attempted to retain deallocated object"
    0x111e91747 <+7>:  movq   %rax, 0x58612(%rip)       ; gCRAnnotations + 8
    0x111e9174e <+14>: int3   
->  0x111e9174f <+15>: nop
```

As far as I understand, the parent should still exist because deinit of the parent has not yet completed. Yet this error seems to suggest that the child can no longer access its `unowned` reference to the parent.

Can anyone shed any light on this?

Comment: Can you show us how you cause `deinit` to be called in your case?

Comment: I've added `viewDidLoad` to show context for init/deinit of the parent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case unowned(unsafe) will do it.
But I would personally not use unowned(unsafe) for anything but bridging objective-c code.

If possible I would try to avoid the need to call child.doStuff() from the deinit() if possible. I have had similar cases where I simply added a .unload() method that my own code was responsible for calling when time needed. In the above example the ViewController could accept this responsibility.

And I guess the utopian solution would be, to find a way where the objects are not so intertwined by design, when/if possible of course.

Example of unload() scenario: (I tested it in the terminal repl, therefore no UIKit)

```
import Foundation

class ViewController {
  let parent = Parent()

  deinit {
    parent.unload()
  }
}

class Parent {

  init() {
    child.doStuff()
  }

  func unload() {
    // Code used to be in deinit
    child.doStuff()
  }

  lazy private var child : Child = Child(parent : self)
}

class Child {

  init(parent : Parent) {
    self.parent = parent
  }

  func doStuff() {
    println(self.parent)
  }

  private unowned var parent : Parent
}

var vc:ViewController? = ViewController()
vc = nil
```

Answer (score 1):

How about the parent passes itself as an argument to the child's method that needs it:

```
class Parent
{
    deinit
    {
        child.doStuff(self)
    }
}

class Child
{
    func doStuff(parent)
    {
        println(parent)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `unowned(unsafe)` fixes this issue. It seems quite dangerous in general, but in this context it's OK because the parent is guaranteed to exist while the child exists.